# No module named 'fraction' in BiAn src to obfuscate smart contract source code

Tags: solidity, python

BiAn is a source code level code obfuscation tool developed for Solidity smart contracts. I run it by [BiAn GitHub](https://github.com/xf97/BiAn).

I've cloned BiAn correctly by:

```
git clone https://github.com/xf97/BiAn
```

After that, I change the directory to the BiAn src and there I run it by:

```
python main.py <contractName>.sol <contractName>.ast
```

But, This error occurred and the process stopped:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\BiAn\src\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from dataflowObfuscation import dataflowObfuscation
  File "...\BiAn\src\dataflowObfuscation.py", line 15, in <module>
    from literal2Exp import literal2Exp
  File "...\BiAn\src\literal2Exp.py", line 5, in <module>
    from generateExp import generateExp
  File "...\BiAn\src\generateExp.py", line 7, in <module>
    from postProcessing import postProcessing
  File "...\BiAn\src\postProcessing.py", line 4, in <module>
    from fraction import Fraction
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fraction'
```

It seems there is no module named fraction in the src. I checked the online file on BiAn's GitHub and see that doesn't exist there too. So, because of that, BiAn can't do its task. What is the solution? How can I find the module?

Comment: FYI Self-answering is allowed; I took the time to post the answer you got from Github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the Fraction package:
`pip3 install Fraction`

Source: https://github.com/xf97/BiAn/issues/3#issuecomment-1577216752